# MongoDB 3.6 crashed due to invariant() failure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

MongoDB crashed twice in 6 hours today due to invariant() failure. We have been using `MongoDB 3.6.3` for more than a year now, but this is the first time that we saw this issue. The extract from the log files is given below for reference -

**Log from 1st failure:**

> 2019-02-27T08:44:51.411+0530 E STORAGE  [conn3385299] WiredTiger error
>   (12) [1551237291:411637][2344:2000827264],
>   file:collection-17055--5635302636308412295.wt, WT_CURSOR.search:
>   C:/MREYE/MongoDB/data\collection-17055--5635302636308412295.wt:
>   handle-read: ReadFile: failed to read 4096 bytes at offset 720363520:
>   Not enough storage is available to process this command.
>
> : Not enough space 2019-02-27T08:44:51.412+0530 F -
>   [conn3385299] Invariant failure: seekRet resulted in status
>   UnknownError: 12: Not enough space at
>   src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_record_store.cpp 1734
>
> > 2019-02-27T08:44:51.412+0530 F -        [conn3385299]
>
> ***aborting after invariant() failure

**Log from 2nd failure:**

> 2019-02-27T13:44:11.594+0530 E STORAGE  [conn20] WiredTiger error (12)
>   [1551255251:594637][54524:2000827264],
>   file:collection-17071--5635302636308412295.wt, WT_CURSOR.search:
>   memory allocation of 28696 bytes failed: Not enough space
>
> 2019-02-27T13:44:11.594+0530 F -        [conn20] Invariant failure:
>   seekRet resulted in status UnknownError: 12: Not enough space at
>   src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_record_store.cpp 1734
>
> 2019-02-27T13:44:11.595+0530 F -        [conn20]
>
> ***aborting after invariant() failure

**Note:**

The MongoDB is on C drive and there is sufficient space left (276 GB) on that drive. The MongoDB data folder size itself is only 65 GB. Any idea what might have caused this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not with your physical memory.

What is the RAM size you are using? Are there any other applications that are consuming more RAM memory?

Refer the below thread for more details

[Invariant failure: seekRet resulted in status](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/6nFGDTn47Kk)

Comment: Thanks for your response! the RAM size is 32 GB. When I checked memory usage immediately after the crash, there was 14 GB available. Also, we do not have any other resource-intensive applications running on that server. Moreover, nothing was changed on the server in the last 1 year, and this was the first time we saw this invariant failure issue.

Comment: Is the issue still persists?

Comment: I restarted the server after the 5th crash and we haven't seen this issue since then - (this was 4 days back).  Nevertheless, I wanted to understand what could have gone wrong suddenly without any change / update / new install done on the system. I was wondering if there was some fault with the storage layer

Comment: Were you creating any index on existing collections that time on a large collection or any memory-consuming operation? Are you using default wired tiger cache size or any specific size mentioned in the config? Also you can search for any issues already reported like this is mongo in https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/SERVER/issues/, if you don't see any existing issues, raise a new issue.

Comment: Yes, the crashes were mostly seen during data import. So it is possible that it was at the time when indexes were being created. Nevertheless, the same data import jobs have been running everyday on schedule since the last 1.5 years, but this issue had never occurred before.  Also, we are using default wired tiger cache size.

Comment: By any chance are you using `--numInsertionWorkers` or `--batchSize` in your `mongoimport` statement? Also, Populating an existing collection with indexes also will consume more resources. When doing bulk load, the suggested best practice is `load the data first and create the index later`